# Multiple inserts with query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a cronjob, that deletes everything from a table then refills it with random values from another table, my problem is it is only inserting 1 row, when I want it to insert 24 different ones that it grabs from the other table. any help will be very much appreciated. btw I know mysql is deprecated.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 24");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE market2");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `market2` (`id`, `pokemon`, `price`, `type`) VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '".$row['pokemon']."', '".$row['type']."', '".$row['price']."') ");
}
```

Is the fixed version for anyone else that has this question.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 24");

mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE market2");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `market2` (`id`, `pokemon`, `price`, `type`) VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '".$row['pokemon']."', '".$row['type']."', '".$row['price']."') ");
}
```

Comment: You need to loop through $row and insert each time. It would be much better with a prepared statement though - one query sent to MySQL, and loop through just the variables instead.

Comment: put the truncate statement before your while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regardless on whether I agree to your methodology, your problem is that you are truncating with each loop. To fix please use the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM market ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 24");
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE market2");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `market2` (`id`, `pokemon`, `price`, `type`) VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '".$row['pokemon']."', '".$row['type']."', '".$row['price']."') ");
}
```